# Como concatenar em uma string o que foi selecionado em um select multiple

Tags: php, javascript, html

Olá. Tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<select id="idselect" class="ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" multiple="multiple" name="idPosto" style="padding: 3px 4px;">

<option value="1"></option>
<option value="2"></option>
<option value="3"></option>
<option value="4"></option>

</select>
```

Preciso que a cada clique que o cliente fizer em uma opção, concatene no `href` do link o `"idselect[]"+valorclicado`.

```html
<a href="selecionados.php?precisoqueconcateneaqui"></a>
```

Supondo que o cliente selecione a opção 2 e 3 o link que formaria seria esse:

```
 meusite.com/selecionados.php?idselect[]=2&idselect[]=3
```

Prefiro que seja com javascript puro, mas se souber alguma forma com jQuery também ajudará bastante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizei o evento `onchange` do select pra alterar a URL toda vez que o usuário clica em algum valor, depois rodo um `for` procurando pelos `options` selecionados e concateno na string. (Não tem problema o último `&`)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('idselect').addEventListener("change", 
           function () {
                 var urlTexto = "selecionados.php?";
                 var options = this.options;
                 var opt;

                 for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
                   opt = options[i];

                   if (opt.selected) {
                     urlTexto += this.id + "[]=" + opt.value + "&";
                   }
                 }
    
                 document.getElementById('linkdinamico').href = urlTexto;
                 console.log(urlTexto);
           });  
}
```

```html
<select id="idselect" class="ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" multiple="multiple" name="idPosto" style="padding: 3px 4px;">

  <option value="1" label="Valor 1"></option>
  <option value="2" label="Valor 2"></option>
  <option value="3" label="Valor 3"></option>
  <option value="4" label="Valor 4"></option>

</select>

<a id="linkdinamico" href="selecionados.php?"></a>
```

Comment: @maicon_carraro , esse código resolveu 80% do meu problema, veja por que não resolveu 100%:

meu urltesto ficou assim:
var urlTexto = 'lista_cadastrados.php?codaprovar=';

No "codaprovar=" eu preciso passar um $user->getCodigo que vem dinamicamente do PHP, veja a página para entender melhor:
http://www.alexandrelima.net.br/estagio/Paginas/lista_cadastrados.php

Preciso de algum forma para mandar também o getCodigo para dentro da função e também concatenar junto.

Comment: @AlexandreLima você consegue criar um input `hidden` com o valor do `codAprovar`? ai fica fácil de ficar 100% :)

Comment: que ai depois do `for` tu coloca `urlTexto += "codaprovar=" + document.getElementById('seuinputHidden').value;`

Answer (score 2):

Em resposta à pergunta podes fazer assim:

```
function changeHref(e) {
    var options = [].map.call(this.selectedOptions, function(el){ // capturar as opções escolhidas
        return el;
    });
    var root = link.href.split('?')[0]; // ir buscar o caminho do url
    var queryString = options.map(function (opt) {  // gerar a queryString
        return 'idselect[]=' + opt.value;
    }).join('&');
    link.href = [root, '?', queryString].join('');  // montar o href e aplicar
}

var select = document.getElementById('idselect');
var link = document.getElementById('selectTarget'); // aqui dei um ID ao <a>, podes fazer assim ou de outra maneira se quiseres
select.addEventListener('click', changeHref);
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnu3xkwz/

Mas parece-me que podias fazer isso também só com um `<form>`, sem precisares de JavaScript. Quando carregar no botão para enviar o próprio browser se encarrega de enviar as opções escolhidas para o servidor.

Nesse caso ficaria assim:

```
<form action="/echo/html/">
    <select id="idselect" class="ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" multiple="multiple" name="idselect[]">
        <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
        <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
        <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
        <option value="4">Opção 4</option>
    </select>
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Mais limpo, sem JavaScript.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnu3xkwz/1/

**Nota:** Nos exemplos coloquei o CSS fora do HTML, assim é mais fácil de manter o código.